# Using Sphinx with Regex to search a number plate table

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine, sphinx

I would be ever grateful if someone could advise me here please. I am new to sphinx
and have installed it onto my server with the test database/index example working.

I am now in the position where I need to change the setting in the sphinx.conf file and
to create a new index etc.

My table layout is as follows:

```
Name: listings_dvla
===================
id -> Unsigned INT, primary key
characters -> varchar(15) FULLTEXT indexed
active -> bool
price -> decimal(10,2)
```

This table contains 30,000,000 rows and before I was using mysql to query the database
for similar number plates using the following query (assuming i searched "kev"):

```
SELECT characters, price 
FROM listings_dvla 
WHERE active=TRUE 
AND characters REGEXP '^[a-z0-9]*[(k)]+[a-z0-9]?[(e)(3)]+[a-z0-9]?[(v)]+[a-z0-9]*' 
ORDER BY characters ASC
LIMIT 0, 12
```

What the regex is doing is saying "find me a K followed by an E or 3 followed by a V"
This query can take over a minute depending on the search, I need it to be under a few
seconds.

So my questions are:

1. Is Sphinx built to handle this requirement?
2. Can Sphinx do regular expressions that would be built up at runtime depending on
   the user's input
3. How do I even begin to go about doing this?

Comment: If you can, try to just use plain mysql for this.

Answer (score 1):

Answered here
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=8945